# How to retrieve the largest and smallest value from a list recursively?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to return a tuple with the smallest and highest value in a list, but I can not use the max() and min() functions of python.

My function has to be recursive

no background

```
def minmax(lista):

    if(len(lista) == 0):
        raise ValueError('Cannot find the maximum of an empty list.')

    if len(lista) == 1:
        return (lista[0], lista[0])
    else:
        maxValue = minmax(lista[1:])
        print(maxValue if maxValue > lista[0] else lista[0])
```

minmax([1,2,3]) = (1, 3)
minmax([49, 1, 6, 10]) = (1, 49)

Comment: Why can't you use `min`, `max`? They're builtins and so they are available on every distribution. And why does the function has to be recursive? That's going to lead to problems for `len(lista) > 1000` (at least for the default settings). And finally, what is your specific programming problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns
1. ValueError if lista is empty or None
2. Tuple (lista[0], lista[0]) if list is of one element
3. Tuple of (min, max) in all other cases

```
def minmax(lista, min_value=None, max_value=None):
    if lista is None or len(lista) == 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot find the maximum of an empty list.')

    check_value = lista[0]
    if min_value is None:
        min_value = check_value
    elif check_value < min_value:
        min_value = check_value

    if max_value is None:
        max_value = check_value
    elif check_value > max_value:
        max_value = check_value

    if len(lista) == 1:
        return min_value, max_value
    else:
        return minmax(lista[1:], min_value, max_value)
```

Comment: I can not add parameters in my function

Comment: You don't need to. You can call it with ```minmax(lista)```